# How do you "try" a suru verb? Like "to try to cook"

Tags: grammar, verbs, conjugations, subsidiary-verbs, volitional-form

According to the internet, to say you try an action you need to use the volitional form + *to suru*. So *miroutosuru* is "to try to see". But what about *suru* verbs like *ryouri suru* ("to cook")?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A *suru* verb consists of a noun + *suru*. All conjugation is done on *suru*.

If you want to use the construction *-(y)ō to suru*, on a *suru* verb like *ryōri suru*, you have to find the volitional of *suru*, which is *shiyō*, giving

> 料理しようとする *ryōri shiyō to suru*

---

There is also a different construction for "to try to [verb]", namely, *-te miru*. Again, for a *suru* verb, you would find the *te*-form of *suru*, which is *shite*, giving

> 料理してみる *ryōri shite miru*

For the difference between these two constructions for "to try to" you can read the question [What is the difference between "verb＋て＋みる" and "verb＋(よ)う+とする"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19038/1628)

Depending on the context, the second construction 料理してみる might actually be more appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply follow that rule. The volitional form of *suru* is *siyou*, so you can say *ryouri siyou to suru* (料理しようとする). There is nothing wrong if there are two suru's.

By the way, the volitional form of *miru* is not *mirou* but *miyou*. *Miru* is a vowel-stem verb.