# 俺は考えてみた - Literally translates to I'll think and see?

Tags: meaning, subsidiary-verbs, sentence

It literally translates to that but does it actually mean I'll try to think? Or I'll give it a thought?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/19040/9831

Comment: `I'll try.. I'll give..` <- 考えてみ**た** is past form, so it'd be more like "I **tried** to think,  I **gave** it a thought", no?

Answer (score 3):

みる in this context is an important [subsidiary verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18952/5010) meaning "to try ～ing". た is the ta-form (past tense) of みる. The sentence means "I gave it a thought" or "I tried thinking about it."