# What's the use of the て-form in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, て-form

While reading manga a character stole a power from another guy and said:

> ちょっとこいつの力を試してみたくてな。

I wonder what's the use of the て-form in みたい?. 
What would be the difference with こいつの力を試してみたいな

Answer (score 3):

It's an example of [te-form for reason](https://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/te-form-cause-reason.html), but the subsequent part ("I'm doing this" or "I stole this power") is omitted because it can be inferred from the context. In short, this te-form means "because".

- 試す: to try it
- 試してみる: to try it and see what happens (みる is a subsidiary verb explained [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19038/5010))
- 試してみたい: to want to try it and see what happens
- 試してみたく**て**: **cuz** I wanna try it and see what happens

Comment: Awesome, thanks!