# ~くて on a verb? How do you indicate desire?

Tags: grammar, verbs, i-adjectives

「右手【みぎて】で描【か】いた、今ここに避難所【ひなんじょ】はないんだ。息【いき】を吸【す】いこんだ。つまらない世界【せかい】壊【こわ】したくて。」
Translation: Drawn with my right hand, here, now, as for the shelter, there is none. I inhaled. The boring world wants to be destroyed/broken.

How does one indicate desire correctly if both "~kute" and "tai" indicate it? It would make sense if "~kute", like i've heard, is an ending to an i form adjective, but why is it on a verb like "kowasu"? I provided context as well as the phrase in question because it's such a context based language.

I'm sure I'm just confused somewhere, but I really want to clear this up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

たくて is the te-form of たい "want to". The form たくて only has one function, to make a subordinate clause of the verb before ("wanting to V", "want to V, so/and"), that connects to a main verb (predicate), unless it is used with certain idioms that need te-form for other reasons.

Then where did the main verb go? In this case, the sentence is inverted. The predicate it connects to is actually the previous one.

> つまらない世界壊したくて、息を吸いこんだ。
>   *I breathed in, wanting/wishing to destroy the boring world.*

Answer (score 1):

～たい is an auxiliary verb that conjugates like an い adjective. 壊す + たい + て = 壊したくて.

Comment: I understand, but why does the te form mean anything different here than just using tai? I know the te form can be used to link sentences, but it doesn't seem like it's doing that here. Why does it work?

Comment: Perhaps this is related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/68627/whats-the-use-of-the-%e3%81%a6-form-in-this-sentence