# Difference between 試みる and 試す

Tags: word-choice, words, usage, nuances, word-usage

1. 何度か**試みた**が、失敗した.
2. 何度か**試した**が、失敗した.

Is there a difference between those sentences? I have the feeling that the second one is more about trying smothing out like for the first time and see what happens and the first one is more about tryining something probably again and again.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! [What is the difference between “verb＋て＋みる” and “verb＋(よ)う+とする”?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19038/what-is-the-difference-between-verb%ef%bc%8b%e3%81%a6%ef%bc%8b%e3%81%bf%e3%82%8b-and-verb%ef%bc%8b%e3%82%88%e3%81%86%e3%81%a8%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b) Does naruto's answer in the link answer to you question?

Answer (score 2):

These seem to be used in the same contexts a lot, but there are some cases where their usage differs.

試す - Trying something with the motive of discovering something's qualities.

試みる - Trying something without knowing what the result will be.

- Is seen used in more formal situations too.

So for these sentences, based on the goal it would change. 試す would show that you're constantly trying to figure out something, but it never goes your way perhaps. Such as testing a product for something. 試みる would be trying something out without knowing the end result, so like doing an experiment to test this product, but what sort of things will pop up are unknown.

Definitions I used are below!

*This is just my own sort of feeling as well, so there may be some parts that are off, so I would love to hear other people's thoughts!*

---

**試す**

Definition:

> Google: 本当かどうか、それでよいかどうかなどを知ろう（確かめよう）と、実際にやってみる。

*Actually trying to doing something, or checking if something is true / good.*

> Native Intuition [(1)](https://okwave.jp/qa/q4088136.html#:%7E:text=%E3%80%8C%E8%A9%A6%E3%81%99%E3%80%8D%E3%81%AF%E3%80%81%E5%AF%BE%E8%B1%A1%E3%81%A8,%E3%82%92%E8%A9%A6%E3%81%BF%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E9%81%95%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%80%82): 対象となるものの性能・実態を知るためにやってみるというニュアンスが強い

*Strong nuance of discovering something's true state or ability through trying to do something.*

**試みる**

Definition:

> Google:（実際に）どうなるかやってみる。ためしにやってみる。ためす。

*Seeing how something turns out.*

> Native Intuition [(1)](https://okwave.jp/qa/q4088136.html#:%7E:text=%E3%80%8C%E8%A9%A6%E3%81%99%E3%80%8D%E3%81%AF%E3%80%81%E5%AF%BE%E8%B1%A1%E3%81%A8,%E3%82%92%E8%A9%A6%E3%81%BF%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E9%81%95%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%80%82): 結果がどうなるかはわからないがとりあえずやってみるというニュアンスが強い

*Not knowing how something will turn out, but trying it out anyways.*

Answer (score 1):

Both have the same meaning, but in my view, we usually say 試す in a daily conversation, whereas 試みる sounds more formal and professional. I think some Japanese even don't know how to read 試みる.